# ERROR: el huso horario <<p.m.>> no es reconocido, Postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql

tengo una tabla similar a esta:

```
------------------------------
| id |       fecha           |
------------------------------
| 1  |  2018-06-18 14:30:00  |
| 2  |  2018-06-18 14:31:40  |
------------------------------
```

Lo importante es en la fecha, ya que lo necesito para hacer otra consulta.

En Inicio obtengo el ultimo registro de la tabla con la **funcion Ultimo**:

```
    public static DataTable Ultimo()
    {
        DataTable DtResultado = new DataTable("ultimo");
        NpgsqlConnection SqlCon = new NpgsqlConnection(Conexion.Cn);
        NpgsqlCommand SqlDat = new NpgsqlCommand(String.Format("select * from " + table + " order by fecha desc limit 1"), SqlCon);
        SqlCon.Open();
        NpgsqlDataReader dr = SqlDat.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        DtResultado.Load(dr);
        dr.Close();
        SqlDat.Dispose();
        SqlCon.Close();
        return DtResultado;
    }
```

Hasta ahí **casi todo bien**, ya que la **fecha** me retorna bien en mi pc : `2018-06-18 14:31:40`, pero en otra me retorno: `2018-06-18 2:31:40 p.m.`.

El caso es que necesito todos los datos de esa fecha así que dicha `fecha` la envió a la **funcion PorFechaExacta** tal y cual me llega en la anterior consulta:

```
    public static DataTable PorFechaExacta(string date)
    {
        DataTable DtResultado = new DataTable("fechaExacta");
        NpgsqlConnection SqlCon = new NpgsqlConnection(Conexion.Cn);
        Console.Write(date);
        NpgsqlCommand SqlDat = new NpgsqlCommand(String.Format("select * from " + table + " where date(fecha)='"+date+"'"), SqlCon);
        SqlCon.Open();
        NpgsqlDataReader dr = SqlDat.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        DtResultado.Load(dr);
        dr.Close();
        SqlDat.Dispose();
        SqlCon.Close();
        return DtResultado;
    }
```

Y he ahí un error muy largo con titulo:

> ERROR: el huso horario << p.m. >> no es reconocido

Esto solo en caso de otra pc y no en la mía, si alguien supiera como ayudarme se lo agradezco.

Comment: siempre que compares fechas, usa DateTime... hacer un string... Si se requiere y es de vida o muerte, hay que "parsearlo" bien. Saludos

Comment: Ya se que me van a llamar pesado, pero estos problemas siempre tienen dos causas: a) usar fechas como texto, hay que usar siempre DateTime excepto para mostrar la fecha al usuario b) no usar consultas parametrizadas, esto debe hacerse **siempre**, para evitar Sql Injection y este tipo de problemas al comparar fechas.

Answer (score 0):

Debes darle el formato correcto a la fecha, sería algo así:

```
public static DataTable PorFechaExacta(string date)
{
     IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
     DateTime NewDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", culture);
     date = NewDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

     DataTable DtResultado = new DataTable("fechaExacta");
     NpgsqlConnection SqlCon = new NpgsqlConnection(Conexion.Cn);
     Console.Write(date);
     NpgsqlCommand SqlDat = new NpgsqlCommand(String.Format("select * from " + table + " where date(fecha)='"+date+"'"), SqlCon);
     SqlCon.Open();
     NpgsqlDataReader dr = SqlDat.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
     DtResultado.Load(dr);
     dr.Close();
     SqlDat.Dispose();
     SqlCon.Close();
     return DtResultado;
 }
```

Saludos